# python / django / deploy настройки регистрации/почты

Tags: python, django

На локал хосте регистрация работает,пытаюсь задеплоить но совсем не понимаю принципа.Что куда надо вносить в SETTING и надо ли куда-то ещё.
Подскажите плс.доки или может норм пример или что-нибудь ещё что бы разобраться

Comment: Вносить, очевидно, параметры подключения к вашему почтовому серверу в [соответствующих настройках Django](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/email.html)

Comment: Также добавьте Ваш сервер в `ALLOWED_HOSTS`